# SQL Server sp_configure options?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, configuration

Does anybody know where I can find a list of all the parameter options for sp_configure?  It isn't really jumping out at me when I search online for possible variations and the capabilities of sp_configure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At least three times on the [sp_configure page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188787.aspx), you have ["Setting Server Configuration Options"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189631.aspx).

- In the table for the row "config_value"
- Under "Advanced Options"
- At the bottom

This page also shows what happens if you run `sp_configure` with a blank `@configname`

> If not specified, the complete list of options is returned.

This applies from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2008 pages